# Conditional Permutations

Tags: probability, permutations

There are four teams (A, B, C, D) participating in a swimming tournament ; each having three participants. In how many ways can the 12 participants can be made to sit in a row such that each of the team A members are sandwiched by participants from the other teams?

Comment: I know that A's should not occupy the end sits and also they must not to be together.  I tried to subtract the conditions from the total ways but I'm missing a point

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. It will make an answerer's life a lot easier if you show us the work you have done, and we'll be more encouraged to help you,

Comment: Think of it this way:  order the three members of $A$, order the other $8$, now count the way to partition the $8$ into four non-empty groups.

Comment: @lulu: I think you mean the other **9**

Comment: @trueblueanil  Right.  $12-3=9$ not $8$.  Brain not working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

In the diagram below, the bullets represent members of the "other" teams,
and the up arrows, places where members of team A can be inserted.

You should be able to figure it out from here.

$\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet$

> Choose 3 places from 8 for A team members, permute them, permute 9"others"

Answer (score 0):

Think of the question this way:
Since there are four teams and each team has three members i.e., $12$ total members then there will be $12$ seats required.
Now, since Team $A$ members have to be sandwitched by other team members so, on the first seat, we can choose a member to seat out of $12-3=9$ (i.e., Total - Team $A$ members). That means on the first seat 1 out of $9$ members can sit. Then on the second seat there will be $1$ out of $8$ (but depends, may be you want Team A members to sit on second seat). Now do this for every seat until you get your answer!